# How can I increase the number of times to block for incorrect password?

Tags: ip-blocking

I manage a dedicated server and a VPS. The run on CentOS and I access them through SSH and DirectAdmin. These servers have a low tolerance for wrong password and I frequently block my IP out and need to contact the web hosting company to sort things out.

My questions:

Is there anyway that I can increase the number of times that I enter the password incorrectly. At the moment it is only twice. With my habits I need at least 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

This (temporary) block is most likely applied with [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) (see [manual](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8)).

You can find the correct Fail2ban Jail for SSH from `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` and increase the amount of retries (`maxretry`), e.g.

```
[ssh-iptables]
enabled  = true
filter   = sshd
action   = iptables[name=SSH, port=ssh, protocol=tcp]
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 10
```

Another useful jail option is `bantime`, ban duration in seconds. It defaults to `600`. While I think this is a reasonable penalty for any admin who can mistype password over 10 times, you may disagree. :)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately there is not a fail2ban directory or jail.conf anywhere inside /etc.